# ADF - passing parameters within string to SQL Lookup

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm writing a pipeline, where I fetch SQL queries from a metadata database in a lookup with the hope to execute those later on in the pipeline. Imagine a string stored in a database:

`"SELECT * FROM @{pipeline().parameters.SchemaName}.@{pipeline().parameters.TableName}"`

My hope was when passing this string to another Lookup activity, it would pick up the necessary parameters. However it's being passed to the activity as-is, without parameter substitution and I'm getting errors as a result. Is there any clean fix for this or am I trying to implement something not supported by ADF natively?

I found a work-around is just wrapping the string in a series of replace() statements, but hoping something simpler exists.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try below query in the Dynamic Content text box:

```
@concat('SELECT * FROM ',pipeline().parameters.SchemaName,'.',pipeline().parameters.TableName)
```

Comment: The dynamic context box is configured such like this: @activity('Lookup Query').output.firstRow.SourceQuery, as the whole idea is to be able to store query templates in a metadata database and leverage them in the pipeline. I don't want to lock the pipeline into only a single pattern.

Comment: You can store the query string in the format I added above, I think in your case it is considering it as a string rather than a parameter, can you try replacing the query string and try again, let me know if you face any issues, we can debug further